# install a c# com dll for use by vbscript classic asp website

Tags: c#, dll, vb6

I have a Classic ASP website with vb6 dll's and all is ok with the world, but now I have some extra functionality that has been completed using c# into a COM DLL. In the dev environment this is working, but now I wish to move this DLL onto another machine.

My question is what is the best way to do this?

I have seen answers such as "add it to the GAC" or, "in needs a strong name", etc.

What happened to the good old regsvr32?

Comment: regsvr32 is a utility for COM. As you've written - you need to install it to GAC, to access it from .NET application.

Comment: @Ivan - he is asking how to use it in native clients such as _"vbscript...vb6"_ not from .NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regsvr32 is still relevant today but you can't use it with .NET, only native DLLs.  .NET has a special way to register COM-types as we shall soon see.

Regsvr32 works by invoking the **DllRegisterServer** export. **DllRegisterServer** gives the library a chance to register *COM classes; type libraries; interfaces* etc.  This export is not present in .dlls created by .NET which makes sense because they are not COM by default.    You can easily see these differences if you open up a .NET or non-.NET .dll in *Dependency Walker/Viewer*.

Here's a native c++ ActiveX dll I made earlier (Note the **DllRegisterServer** export on the right):

[image]

And here is a managed .dll. (Note there are **no exports** let alone DllRegisterServer):

[image]

If you have marked your c# class as COM-visible then you can complete the COM-registration by invoking:

**regasm** *assemblyFile*[options]

[Tell me more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6(v=vs.110).aspx)

This will place the necessary entries into the Windows Registry.

There is no need for the GAC because native COM clients (VB6) do not use the GAC

Comment: Fantastic. So all that is needed is to place the dll where ever and call regasm to register it.

Comment: So long as .NET is installed yes. :)